# java selecting an instance of an object

Tags: java, object, input, java.util.scanner

I have a fleet. fleet.java

Each fleet has a set of ships. ship.java

Each ship has a set of crewmembers. crewmember.java

Within Main I am adding Ships to the fleet and Crewmembers to the ships, read in from a roster of both.

From the first file I add a new ship to an arraylist.
From the second file I add a new crewmember to an arraylist.

this.addships(ship)

this.shipname.addcrewmember(crewmember)

How do I change the shipname in the above statement based on the token from the input file?

```
public void loadStarships( String filename ) {
    File file = new File( filename );
    Scanner scan;

    try {
        scan = new Scanner( file );

        while( scan.hasNextLine() ) {
            String line = scan.nextLine();
            String[] tokens = line.split(",");
            Starship star = null;

            star = new Starship( tokens[0], tokens[1], tokens[2]);

            this.addStarship( star );
        }

        scan.close();

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void loadCrew( String filename ) {
    File file = new File( filename );
    Scanner scan;
    try {
        scan = new Scanner( file );

        while( scan.hasNextLine() ) {
            String line = scan.nextLine();
            String[] tokens = line.split(",");
            CrewMember member = null;

            member = new CrewMember( tokens[0], tokens[1], tokens[2], tokens[4]);

            this.tokens[3].addCrewMember( member );
        }

        scan.close();

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public Starship( String name, String registry, String level) {
    this.name = name;
    this.registry = registry;
    this.level = level;
    this.crewmembers = new ArrayList<CrewMember>();
}

//adds new crew members
public void addCrewMember( CrewMember crewmembers ) {
    this.crewmembers.add( crewmembers );
    this.numberOfCrewMembers++;
}

public CrewMember( String name, String position, String rank, String species ) {
    this.name = name;
    this.position = position;
    this.rank = rank;
    this.species = species;
}
//set the fleet name and the maximum number of starships
public Fleet(String name) {
    this.name = name;
    this.starships = new ArrayList<Starship>();
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to iterate through a list of ships and trying to figure out how to add crew to the second ship after the first has been fully crewed? You're better off posting the actual code that demonstrates what's going on, along with some sample data. Asking people to guess isn't going to be very efficient.

Comment: Use a ``java.util.Map<String,Ship>`` with the shipname as a key. Make sure to implement ``equals`` and ``hashCode`` in the ``Ship`` class (let your IDE generate those).

Answer (score 0):

The first rule of software design is "use the correct data structure for the job." As it stands, you're saving instances of ship to an `ArrayList`, which only allows you to retrieve elements by index.

Although you didn't provide the sample data requested, it's easy enough to infer that `token[3]` is the name of the ship to which the crew member belongs, so you need to figure out how to retrieve an object by name.

Luckily, Java provides you with the [HashMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html), which stores key-value pairs. You can use the ship's name as a key. When you pass that key to the HashMap, it'll return the value associated with that key -- in your case, the instance of ship that you need.

1) Make sure your class imports `java.util.HashMap;`

2) Declare your HashMap. Instead of:

```
ArrayList<Starship> ships = new ArrayList<Starship>();
```

use:

```
HashMap<String, Starship> = new HashMap<String, Starship>();
```

In this situation, a String representing the name of the ship is the key. The instance of ship with that name is the value.

3) When adding a new ship, you're going to have to update your `addStarship()` method to take a String arg in addition to the Starship arg it already takes:

```
public void addStarship(String name, Starship ship)
```

4) In the body of `addStarship()` you have to add the ship using the `put()` method:

```
ships.put(name, ship);
```

Remember, here, `ships` is the instance of `HashMap` that you're using to store your ships. `name` is a String representing the name of the ship, and `ship` is the ship object.

5) When you're trying to retrieve the ship, you use the `get()` method:

```
ships.get(name);
```

In your case, the code might look like this:

```
ships.get(tokens[3].addCrewMember(member));
```

Keep in mind that with `HashMap`, you can no longer retrieve values by index like you could with `ArrayList`. `HashMap` is by definition, and unordered collection, meaning the first element of the structure may or may not be the the first object you added, and even if you accessed an object at the first position, there's no guarantee that it'll still be in that slot if you try to access it later -- its position in the `HashMap` may have changed, so you'll typically only be retrieving values using the key.

Please make sure you read the official documentation that I linked, above.